# Using gpu.js for cellular automata

Tags: javascript, cellular-automata, gpu.js

I'm trying to run 1D cellular automata using gpu.js, but it looks that my code without gpu.js is 20 times faster. I cannot understand where is the issue.

The code below runs cellular automata for rule 30 starting from single one ON cell. The length of the automata is 2001 cells. The code calculates the first 10000 generations both using CPU and GPU and for CPU it takes 0.16 sec while for GPU 3.2 sec.

```js
gen = [];
for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++) gen.push(0);
gen.push(1); 
for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++) gen.push(0);

const gpu = new GPU();
const kernel = gpu.createKernel(function(x) {
  const x1 = x[this.thread.x-1];
  const x2 = x[this.thread.x];
  const x3 = x[this.thread.x+1];
  return x1+x2+x3-2*x1*x2-x2*x3-2*x1*x3+2*x1*x2*x3;
}).setOutput([gen.length]);

kernelCPU = function(x){
  var res = [];
  x.unshift(0);
  x.push(0);
  for (var i = 1; i < x.length-1; i++) {
    x1 = x[i-1];
    x2 = x[i];
    x3 = x[i+1];
    res.push(x1+x2+x3-2*x1*x2-x2*x3-2*x1*x3+2*x1*x2*x3);
  }
  return res;

}
var t0 = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i< 10000; i++) {

  gen = kernelCPU(gen);
}
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Took " + (t1 - t0)/1000 + " seconds for CPU")
var t0 = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i< 10000; i++) {

  gen = kernel(gen);
}
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Took " + (t1 - t0)/1000 + " seconds for GPU.")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gpu.js/1.10.4/gpu.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you running this on integrated graphics? Your code takes 8-9 seconds for me.

Comment: Yes.. when I run the benchmark code on gpu.js page it is 7 times faster if use GPU, but my code is slower. Probably I missed something...

Comment: Try running your for-loop in the kernel. That's what the benchmark is doing, too.

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to parallel since cellular automata are calculated generation by generation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the loop

```
for (var i = 0; i< 10000; i++) {
    gen = kernel(gen);
}
```

There is some non-zero overhead associated with calling a GPU kernel function. You only have 2001 cells that can be computed in parallel - after the initial overhead of calling the GPU kernel function these should be computed much faster than on the CPU. However because you encounter that GPU call overhead *10,000* times you're more than losing any performance gains you achieve.